# Dynamic Editable Grid for Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I present a grid to edit children of a parent object AND allow the user to add new child objects on the same view?

If I use a table, how do I redraw the table when a new child is added?  Is there a control (hopefully that does not use jQuery) which will provide something more elegant?

My object graph looks like this:

```
person: {
    name: 'Joe Blow',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Mary Blow',
            gender: 'F',
            age: '18',
            hair: 'Brown',
            eyes: 'Green'
        },
        {
            name: 'Frank Blow',
            gender: 'M',
            age: '21',
            hair: 'Bald',
            eyes: 'Blue'
        }
    ]
}
```

The view must have two forms... one to add a new child (basically just a name)... and a grid to allow the properties of each child to be edited.

Side note: I'm also worried about so many children being added that the columns shrink to an unusable size OR the grid grows too wide that it distorts the app's navigation and elements on the left.

Comment: Here is a small example fiddle to help you understand: http://jsfiddle.net/L71rtwrc/

Comment: Thanks, however it is important that I be able to edit the item in the table.

Comment: well search for "contenteditable" and try to implement it, or disabling/enabling input fields on 'edit' click..

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zy9cwjbt/

Comment: Whoa... you've cleared up my confusion.  I was under the impression that `ng-repeat` only draws the table one time, when the view is rendered.  Your example shows that I am wrong.  Adding a new item to the array causes the next row to be drawn.  Outstanding!

Comment: the beauty of angular. You are welcome.